# Angular: how to fire ngChange when input type="number" but not entered a number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, frontend

I'm building an angular directive, where I have two number inputs and both together represent an age range.

What I want to achieve is being able to use this directive the following way:

```
<input-age-range
    name="ageRange"
    ng-model="filterUpdateVM.ageRange">
</input-age-range>
<span ng-if="myCtrlVM.form.ageRange.$error.ageRange">
    Please, enter a valid age range.
</span>
```

and be able to show a custom error when the entered age range is not correct.

My directive html template looks this way:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="number"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Minimum age"
           name="ageMin"
           min="18"
           max="80"
           ng-change="checkAndValidateAgeRange()"
           ng-model="ageRange.ageMin"
           ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="number"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Maximum age"
           name="ageMax"
           min="18"
           max="80"
           ng-change="checkAndValidateAgeRange()"
           ng-model="ageRange.ageMax"
           ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
</div>
```

Every time the user types anything in an input, I wish to check the if the entered range is correct:

- Both ages should be numbers
- Both ages should be between 18 and 80
- ageMin <= ageMax

So far `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` will let the ngChange function inside my directive to be triggered in case any of the ages entered is not between the desired age range (18-80) - this way I can do some checking and set an input error if there's any and show it.

My problem here is that if the age entered at first is not a number, ngChange is not called: it won't be able to do the error checking so there won't be any errors to be shown. How can I have my ngChange function called in this case, without changing my input `type="number"`?

**EDIT: Jsfiddle added:** http://jsfiddle.net/afkf96qh/

Comment: If `type="number"` then how someone can enter **not a number**?

Comment: @Kumkar i.e. : 'eeeee' )

Comment: By typing any character.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov then on `ng-change` we can check if value conains **eeeee** or not

Comment: @Kumkar if entered a minAge that is not a number, you get a `form.ageMin.$error.number` error but ngChange is not triggered. I want to check this error inside my directive to set the validity of ngModel and being able to capture errors when using my directive.

Comment: @charliebrownie only **e** character is acceptable when we use `type="number"`

Comment: @Kumkar I'm afraid not

Comment: Can you add your code on `jsfiddle?` then only we can sure it's works or not

Comment: @charliebrownie Would you mind to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [pen](http://codepen.io/) and then let's see?

Comment: and check one more thing , `ng-change` is working in any case or not

Comment: @Viplock ngChange is working. Plus, by using `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` is also triggering if number entered is not in the min-max range.

Comment: about type="number" and characters:
in Chrome only 'e' char is valid
when in IE11 you can enter whatever, so basically you can never rely on this

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Ohhh, wasn't aware of it, thanks for same. What about using `ng-pattern` with **RegEX**?

Comment: @RameshRajendran JsFiddle added (edited question).

Comment: @VilasKumkar JsFiddle added (edited question).

Comment: @Viplock JsFiddle added (edited question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after a day of trying to figure out what was going on, I achieved the behavior I was looking for.

First of all, `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` had nothing to do in solving my problem, so I removed that out of my input. My directive html template looks this way now:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="number"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Minimum age"
           name="ageMin"
           min="18"
           max="80"
           ng-model="ageRange.ageMin"
           ng-change="checkAndValidateAgeRange()">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="number"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Maximum age"
           name="ageMax"
           min="18"
           max="80"
           ng-model="ageRange.ageMax"
           ng-change="checkAndValidateAgeRange()">
</div>
```

The problem that caused not triggering `ng-change="checkAndValidateAgeRange()"` was the way I was initializing the `ageRange` variable at the **ngModel** `$render` function:

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {

    var directive = {
        templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        require:  ['^form', 'ngModel'],
        link: linkFunc
    };

    return directive;

    /////////

    function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
        scope.form = ctrls[0];
        scope.ageRange = {};
        scope.checkAndValidateAgeRange = checkAndValidateAgeRange;

        var ngModel = ctrls[1];
        ngModel.$render = getAgeRange;

        function checkAndValidateAgeRange() {
            // fired when the model changes
        };

        // $render function
        function getAgeRange() {
            scope.ageRange.ageMin = ngModel.$viewValue.ageMin;
            scope.ageRange.ageMax = ngModel.$viewValue.ageMax;
        };
    };

};
```

In some cases, both of the **ngModel** object's properties passed to the directive - `ageMin` and `ageMax` - could be `undefined`.

And we all know what happens when we have an input with restrictions such as `type="[whatever]"`, `min="18"` or `max="80"` and the data entered in that input does not follow those requirements: it is set to `undefined` in the model.

So, if the above properties were initially passed to the directive set to `undefined` and you entered a value in the `<input type="number ...>` that, for example, was not numeric... the binded model's value would still be `undefined`, so there wouldn't be any changes in the model making the `ng-change` not trigger.

What I finally did to solve this, was to initialize both `ageRange.ageMin` and `ageRange.ageMax` to `null` if they are passed as `undefined`, at my `$render` function:

```
ngModel.$render = getAgeRange;

// $render function
function getAgeRange() {
    scope.ageRange.ageMin = ngModel.$viewValue.ageMin || null;
    scope.ageRange.ageMax = ngModel.$viewValue.ageMax || null;
};
```

This way, when entering an invalid input the model's property value will change from `null` to `undefined` causing the `ng-change` to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afkf96qh/8/)

```
$scope.checkAndValidateAgeRange = function(name, model) {
    if (name === 'ageMin') {
        if (angular.isNumber(model)) {
            if (model < $scope.age.min) {
                $scope.minAgeMessage = 'You are under age';
            } else if (model > $scope.age.max) {
                $scope.minAgeMessage = 'You are too old';
            } else {
                $scope.minAgeMessage = '';
            }
        } else {
            $scope.minAgeMessage = 'Enter Only Numbers';
            $scope.ageRange.ageMin = null;
        }
    }

    if (name === 'ageMax') {
        if (angular.isNumber(model)) {
            if (model <= $scope.ageRange.ageMin) {
                $scope.maxAgeMessage = 'You are under age';
            } else if (model > $scope.age.max) {
                $scope.maxAgeMessage = 'You are too old';
            } else {
                $scope.maxAgeMessage = '';
            }
        } else {
            $scope.maxAgeMessage = 'Enter Only Numbers';
            $scope.ageRange.ageMax = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your answer, but I'm not trying to figure out what the logic would be (I already have it!). In your case, your initializing ageMin and ageMax with some default values, thing that I'm not interested in.
I'd just love to be able to trigger my ngChange function whatever value is entered.

Comment: Also, inside my directive I'd use `ngModel.$setValidity('ageRange', true);` in order to handle and show errors from outside the directive - those places where I'd use it -, instead of having this logic done inside the directive.

Comment: I know in the fiddle the basic logic was put inside a controller, but the reason I did this was to prove what I had was working properly and you had an idea of what I had.

Comment: Also want to take advantage of the min-max input attributes, in your case you are validating this way `model <= $scope.ageRange.ageMin` what it's also visible at `scope.form.ageMin.$error.` Do you get my point? :-)

Comment: That's the reason I asked for code snippet, You could have added your directive in given fiddle, it might help me to understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: I finally solved my issue, I already answered the question myself. If you're interested you can check it out! http://stackoverflow.com/a/42417088/3023947

Answer (score -1):

you can't use allowInvalid on type='number' as given [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D). You can set type='text' and then handle validation inside the ng-change handler if your intent if using type='number' is showing validation messages.

To set validity of form inside a controller refer to [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Comment: I finally solved my issue, I already answered the question myself. If you're interested you can check it out!

No need to change the type from `number` to `text`.